# Update a Pandas column where the new values are a combination of the values in the column and another column in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Sampe df

```
df = {
         'DestSystemNote1': ['ISIN            |CUSIP         |CalTyp1',
                             'ISIN            |CUSIP         |CalTyp1',
                            'ISIN            |CUSIP         |CalTyp1'
                            ],
         'InstrumentDescription': ['YMM1 Comdty', 'YMM2 Comdty', 'YMM3 Comdty'],

    }

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['DestSystemNote1','InstrumentDescription'])
print(df)
```

Sample:

Value in `InstrumentDescription` is `YMM0 Comdty`

Value in `DestSystemNote1` before update is:

```
"ISIN=            |CUSIP=         |CalTyp=1"
```

Value in `DestSystemNote1` after:

```
"ISIN=YMM0 Comdty            |CUSIP=         |CalTyp=1"
```

My attempt:

```
mask = (df['DestSystemNote1'] == "ISIN=            |CUSIP=         |CalTyp=1") 
df.loc[mask, 'DestSystemNote1'] = "ISIN=" + df.loc[mask, 'InstrumentDescription'].str.upper() + "             |CUSIP=         |CalTyp=1"
```

Peter

Comment: Please share sample input and expected output.

Comment: I don't follow the question at all. What are we supposed to be answering exactly? What does the df look like?

Comment: Does this make it a little clearer? The updated field just needs to have another fields value inserted into the existing string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this,

```
mask = (df['DestSystemNote1'] == "ISIN            |CUSIP         |CalTyp1")

df.loc[mask, "DestSystemNote1"] = (df.loc[mask, :]
                                   .apply(lambda x: x['DestSystemNote1'].
                                          replace("ISIN",
                                                  "ISIN=%s" % x['InstrumentDescription']),
                                          axis=1))

print(df)
```

output,

```
                                     DestSystemNote1 InstrumentDescription
0  ISIN=YMM1 Comdty            |CUSIP         |Ca...           YMM1 Comdty
1  ISIN=YMM2 Comdty            |CUSIP         |Ca...           YMM2 Comdty
2  ISIN=YMM3 Comdty            |CUSIP         |Ca...           YMM3 Comdty
```

Comment: Hi @Sushanth I'm getting ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame

Comment: Hi @Sushanth, I just need to strip away the blank values after Comdty. I achieved this adding another line. is there a way to edit your solution so there are no trailing blanks after Comdty?


df["DestSystemNote1"]= df["DestSystemNote1"].str.replace("Comdty            ", "Comdty", case = True)

ISIN=YMM1 Comdty            |CUSIP         |Ca... becomes 

ISIN=YMM1 Comdty|CUSIP         |CalTyp1

Comment: This should do the job, ```df['DestSystemNote1'] = df['DestSystemNote1'].str.replace("(\s{2,}[^|]*)", "")```